# Добавление даты, битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет, мне нужно выводить какого числа добавлен новый элемент в инфоблок, нашел свойство TIMESTAMP_X, но оно выводит вместе с часами, а как мне выводить только дату?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно форматировать дату так, в стиле D7

```
print (new \Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime($arItem['TIMESTAMP_X']))->format('d.m.Y');
```

Есть старые варианты, например, CDatabase::FormatDate().

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: а как сделать если мне нужны все величины, кроме секунд?

Comment: Вместо d.m.Y нужно использовать свой формат. Например, так: d.m.Y, H:i.
Подробный список поддерживаемых символов при форматировании даты и времени: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php